# Windows Azure custom domain verifies but doesn't save

Tags: azure

I have set up A and CNAME records. When I go to manage domains in the azure portal I enter *alqalam.tv* and *www.alqalam.tv* (my domain). The page shows that it has verified but when I save it shows an error. I have tried storage custom domain but it doesn't even verify.

My *Azure* website subdomain is `alqalam.azurewebsites.net`

I have made DNS lookup: http://www.hscripts.com/tools/HDNT/dns-record.php
and it shows

**Domain              Type     Class        Result**

www.alqalam.tv.   CNAME    IN           Alqalam.azurewebsites.net.

alqalam.tv.       A        IN           94.245.104.73

thank you

Comment: For clarification, have you added the CNAME awverify.www.alqalam.tv in your provider's domain hosting?

Comment: it is optional: I'm quoting manage.windowsazure.com:  "www.yourdomain.com to Alqalam.azurewebsites.net, **or** from awverify.www.yourdomain.com to awverify.Alqalam.azurewebsites.net" thank you

Comment: But you've configured an A record which does require the awverify, could there be a conflict between the CNAME and A record?  Details -> http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

Comment: I did add awverify and verified with both an online tool and azure but still it doesn't work. Please tell me if you think that I can do something else or is there a way to get free technical support.

Comment: Well DNS changes do take sometime to propagate, typically 24 hours.  You may need to be patient while DNS sorts itself out.

Comment: even though I can see that I have the required records from a tool which microsoft referred to?

Answer (score 0):

this did it for me:

- Type          Host                             Answer                                                      TTL
- A             alqalam.tv                  94.245.104.73                                             300
- CNAME   www.alqalam.tv          alqalam.azurewebsites.net                          300
- CNAME   awverify.alqalam.tv       awverify.alqalam.azurewebsites.net           300